# How to specify build condition for objc_exception_throw?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exception, breakpoints

I would like to conditionally enable the `objc_exception_throw` global breakpoint for my app, only when I am doing a Debug build (not when doing a Release or Distribution build).

[image]

Is there a way to specify this build condition in Xcode's Breakpoints window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking doesn't really make a lot of sense, since breakpoints are not compiled into the app bundle - when you compile for Release you are generally sending it out for, well release and it doesn't matter what breakpoints you have set.

You could also check the "continue" checkmark on the row (far right) if you wanted it temporarily disabled, as the system would just go right past it.